# Set Language Sources Key from Command Line

Tags: command-line, input-language

I'd like to change the settings for Language Switcher from the command line (as part of a bash script I run after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) to be like in the screenshot:

[image]

This is how it shows up in `dconf-editor`:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the only keys being changed are `sources` and `xkb-options`. You could simply set those keys to the values seen here using `gsettings`

Answer (score 1):

Changing to Hebrew (second item in the sources list):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```

Changing to English (US) (first item in the sources list):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

*Note:* This does not apply as from Ubuntu 17.10, since it uses GNOME and the keys for the purpose are slightly different.

*Edit:*

Changing the shortcut for switching input source to "Shift+Alt L":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

Comment: thanks Gunnar, but it seems I wasn't clear:
Right after installing Ubuntu, the default key combination to switch between sources is set to `Super+Space` (god knows why...) and I'd like to change it to `ALT+Shift L` from within a bash script I run post-installation.

Comment: @PenguinCSC: Ok, I edited my answer.

Comment: Great! Worked! 
My only problem - I run the script as superuser. This change is user specific. Is there a way to set it globally - so every user that logs in to that machine gets this setting as a default?

Comment: @PenguinCSC: This is untested, but editing `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.gschema.xml` may be what you want.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try.
Thank you!